# Passing data to a CakePHP controller using jQuery's $.post()

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, post, cakephp-1.3

If I'm sending data from an anchor attribute:

```
<a id="123">foo</a>
```

With no `<form>` around it,

Using jquery's $.post() to one of my controllers:

```
    $('.add-fav').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.post('/ajax/addFavorite', function(data){
    id : id
    }, 'json');
});
```

How can I retrieve the data within that controller? I'm not using a model to validate anything, so using Cake's built-in formhelper convention shouldn't matter.

```
     public function addFavorite() {
       $this->autoRender = false;

       $bar = $_POST['id'] // normally I'd do this to get '123' from the anchor id, but it doesn't work since it wasn't submitted within a form

        $dataBack = json_encode($bar);

       if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
            if($this->Session->read('Auth.User')) {
                return $dataBack;
            }
       }
 }
```

I can send a json_encoded associative array as data back to $.post(), but I can't seem to send what was originally sent back (e.g. id which goes through the controller and sending it back). Am I missing something fundamental here or is it not possible to do without sending the data in an input field (hidden maybe) inside of a `<form>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

data to be passed id send as the second argument of `$.post`

```
 $('.add-fav').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.post('/ajax/addFavorite',{id:id}, function(data){
   console.log(data);
    }, 'json');
});
```

Comment: Now I know why I like sticking to $.ajax(), since I actually remember how to properly structure it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well there is a pretty good way to do it with CakePHP JS Helper too.

```
    $this->Js->get('.add-fav')->event('click',
        $this->Js->request(
        array(‘controller’ => ‘ajax’, ‘action' => 'addFavorite'),
           array(
               'data' => 'event.target.id',
               'async' => true,    
               'dataExpression' => true,
               'method' => 'POST',
               //'update' => '#element_id', // to paste the answer of the call
               //'before' => 'alert("Before request")',
               //'complete' => 'alert("Callback when request completed")',
               //'error' => 'alert("Callback for request error")',
               //'success' => 'alert("Success")', //code to execute if success
           )
        )
    );
    echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
```